# How to add image on seiral port in Python?

Tags: python, serial-port

I m using Posiflex printer. Its only support for com port print. I am new to python I got some ideas from google search and i wrote code now I want add logo to receipt printer and I am using Python 3.7. Please help me on this

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4',
baudrate=38400,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
timeout=0)



print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

ser.write(str.encode('\x1b\x40')); # esc @ (init)
ser.write(str.encode('\x0a')); #line feed
ser.write(str.encode('\x0a')); #line feed


################### I want add Image on here #################


#ser.write(str.encode(''))

ser.write(str.encode('123456789012345678901234567890123456789012\n1.SODA POP                1          $3.25\n2.PAPAYA JUICE            1          $2.50'))


ser.write(str.encode('\x1d\x56\x42\x03')); #cut the paper

sleep(1)

ser.close()

I want add company logo on print. My printer only support for serial com port.
```

Comment: Research enough, choose a library and ask a specific question. For example, see [Python-escpos](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#documentation-and-usage).